# Can't get static module loading working with Vuex and vuex-module-decorators

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have trivial Vue app with a root Vuex store with a `user` module. I'm using vuex-module-decorators. I have `store/store-accessor.ts` set up like the [Vuex Nuxt example](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators/blob/master/README.md#accessing-modules-with-nuxtjs). It imports all the module ts files and exports the results of `getModule(user)` as `userStore`. I don't have any typescript compile problems.

When I start my app, which uses `userStore.user.uid` in the HelloWorld component, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at Object.get (index.js?6fc5:121)
    at new HelloWorld (HelloWorld.vue?1d82:17)
    at collectDataFromConstructor (vue-class-component.esm.js?2fe1:97)
    at VueComponent.data (vue-class-component.esm.js?2fe1:172)
```

That stack trace ends in this code in vuex-module-decorators. I marked the error location with comments:

```js
function staticStateGenerator(module, modOpt, statics) {
    var state = modOpt.stateFactory ? module.state() : module.state;
    Object.keys(state).forEach(function (key) {
        if (state.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // If not undefined or function means it is a state value
            if (['undefined', 'function'].indexOf(typeof state[key]) === -1) {
                Object.defineProperty(statics, key, {
                    get: function () {
                        // ERROR HERE, modOpt.store.state has no property "user"
                        // modOpt.store looks like the root store, its state is empty.
                        // modOpt.name is "user", the name of my module.
                        return modOpt.store.state[modOpt.name][key]; 
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Do I need to do something to set up `modOpt.store.state["user"]` to be the `userStore` module or something?

I created a github repo to show the problem: https://github.com/garyo/vuex-problem-test.git
Just git clone that, `yarn install` and `yarn serve` and you should see the error in the JS console.